# Trying to edit my blog website

Tags: html, css

I have this simple PHP website I am building, and I am having some issues getting somethings to work correct.

First off, Id like each POST to have a black border around it, for some reason, it puts the border around the entire webpage instead. Id also like each post to be time stamped, to show when it was posted, but same thing as with the border. all the time stamps are the same, when I add a post, all posts change to the time the newest post was made. I'll post my php below, as well as the  form.php, hopefully its a small fix.

Thanks!

PHP

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="post.css" />

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Daily Dorm News</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Your Daily Dorm News Post! </h1>
<div id="container"> <?php if ( isset($_GET['name']) and preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/", $_GET['name']) ) {

    echo $_GET['name'];

} else {

    echo "You entered an invalid name!\n";

}

?><br>


Your email address is: <?php if ( isset($_GET['email']) and preg_match("/.+@.+\..+/i", $_GET['email']) ) {

    echo $_GET['email'];

} else {

    echo "You didn't enter a proper email address!\n";

}
?><br>
You Posted : <?php echo $_GET["message"]; ?><br>


This event happened :<?php echo $_GET["date"]; ?><br>


</div>
<?php 
/* [INFO/CS 1300 Project 3] index.php 
 * Main page for our app.
 * Shows all previous posts and highlights the current user's post, if any.
 * Includes a link to form.php if user wishes to create and submit a post.
 */ 

require('wall_database.php');

// Fetching data from the request sent by form.php  
$name = strip_tags($_REQUEST['name']);
$email = strip_tags($_REQUEST['email']);
$message = strip_tags($_REQUEST['message']);
$date = strip_tags($_REQUEST['date']);

$is_valid_post = true;
// Checking if a form was submitted
if (isset($_REQUEST['name'])){
  // Fetching data from the request sent by form.php  
$name = strip_tags($_REQUEST['name']);
$email = strip_tags($_REQUEST['email']);
$message = strip_tags($_REQUEST['message']); 
$date = strip_tags($_REQUEST['date']);  
  // Saving the current post, if a form was submitted
  $post_fields = array();
  $post_fields['name'] = $name;
  $post_fields['email'] = $email;
  $post_fields['message'] = $message;
  $post_fields['date'] = $date;
  $success_flag = saveCurrentPost($post_fields);
}

//Fetching all posts from the database
$posts_array = getAllPosts();

require('header.php');
?>
    <p><a href="form.php">Submit a Post</a></p>

    <?php
    if(isset($name)) {
      echo "<h3>Thanks ".$name." for submitting your post.</h3>";
    }
    ?>

    <p>Here are all the posts we have received.</p>
    <ul id="posts_list">
    <div id="posts">
    <?php 

    // Looping through all the posts in posts_array
    $counter = 1;
    foreach(array_reverse($posts_array) as $post){
      $name = $post['name'];
      $email = $post['email'];
      $message = $post['message'];
      $date = $post['date'];
      if ($counter % 2==1)
        $li_class = "float-left";
      else
        $li_class = "float-right";

      echo '<li class="'.$li_class.'"><h3><span>'.$name.'</span> wrote a post.</h3></li>';
      echo '<li class="'.$li_class.'"><h3><span>'.$name.' email is: '.$email.'</span></h3></li>';
      echo '<li class="'.$li_class.'"><h3><span>'.$name.' wrote '.$message.'</span> wrote a post.</h3></li>';
      echo '<li class="'.$li_class.'"><h3><span>This evemt occured on '.$date.'</span></h3></li>';
      date_default_timezone_set('EST');
      echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');

    }
    ?>
    </ul>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Form

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html> 
<head>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Daily Dorm News</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
$('form').submit(function (e) {
    var value;

    // "message" pattern : from 3 to 15 alphanumerical chars

    value = $('[name="message"]').val();
    if (!/^[A-Za-z0-9]{3,15}$/.test(value)) {
        alert('Wrong value for "message".');
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    }

    // "name" pattern : at least 1 digit

    value = $('[name="name"]').val();
    if (!/\d+/.test(value)) {
        alert('Wrong value for "name".');
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
    }
});

});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<h1> <u>Daily Dorm News</u> <br> The best place to get your latest Dorm news </h1>
<form action="posting_wall.php" method="get">
<div id="container">
Name:<input type="text" name="name" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]{3,15}" title="Letters and numbers only, length 3 to 15" required autofocus><br>
E-mail: <input type="email" name="email" maxlength="20" required><br>

Post:<br>

<textarea rows="15" cols="50" name='message'></textarea>
</div>
Date this event took place: <input type="text" name='date' id="datepicker" required> <br>

<input type="reset" value="Reset">
<input type="submit">
</form>
<p><a href="posting_wall.php">Posting Wall</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
h1 {
font-size:200%;
text-decoration:underline;
font-weight:bold;
color:blue;
text-align:center;

}
div#container {
font-size:150%;
text-align:center;
}
div#posts{
border-style:solid;
border-width:5px;
}
```

[IMG]http://i41.tinypic.com/260aog7.jpg[/IMG]

Comment: This isn't a PHP issue, it's a CSS issue

Comment: how so? I added the border css, the border is there, but I want a separate border on each post. It seems its where I put the div id="posts" and the time stamp code. I put it at the end of the PHP file as youcan see, but is that the right place?

Comment: Show us your CSS and we can probably help. You are using PHP to render your posts onto your blog, but I don't know what the CSS that's creating the border is, so I can't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS currently targets

```
div #posts{
}
```

which, from reading your PHP, is the entire post container. If you want a border around each one, you need to add a class to the individual post. In your code, that's the foreach block

I would consider adding a div to wrap each post in with a class like

```
echo '<div class=post>';
  echo '<li class="'.$li_class.'"><h3><span>'.$name.'</span> wrote a post.</h3></li>';
  echo '<li class="'.$li_class.'"><h3><span>'.$name.' email is: '.$email.'</span></h3></li>';
  echo '<li class="'.$li_class.'"><h3><span>'.$name.' wrote '.$message.'</span> wrote a post.</h3></li>';
  echo '<li class="'.$li_class.'"><h3><span>This evemt occured on '.$date.'</span></h3></li>';
  date_default_timezone_set('EST');
  echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');
echo '</div>';
```

Then rewrite your css to say:

```
.post{
     border: 5px solid;
}
```

Comment: ok, where should I wrap it in the div class="post" though? Can you paste where I need to wrap it around?

Comment: I've edited my answer above.

Comment: think I tried that, and it did all the posts, i'll try it now tho and see

Comment: ok it seemed to work, tho id like the border width to go along with the length of the text if possible, maybe make width auto? Also see how all the time stamps are the same time at the bottom of each post? Can that be changed so it stays time stamped for when each post was made? [IMG]http://i41.tinypic.com/260aog7.jpg[/IMG] I added a screenshot so you can see what I mean,

Comment: Make a new question for this. It's a separate issue, and I want to leave this one as it is for future's sake. It's customary to accept my answer (click the check mark) if it helped you out.

Comment: it wont let me do anymore questions on my account. Can you email me to help me out?

Comment: Sure, but I don't have time right this second. Tweet me at @TMurphyMusic, and we can exchange info. I can help out this weekend.

Comment: think i tweeted you correctly, if not just email me horgantm@gmail.com